# Obtain data warehouse storage information in Sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase

I've got a database named `data_base` with a few tables: `table1`, `table2`, and `table3`. I want to find the total data storage in `data_base` in terabytes. I found the following code on Sybase's help site:

```
sp_spaceusage 'display summary [using unit= {KB | MB | GB | PAGES} ]', 
{'table' | 'index'}, name
[,where_clause [,order_by[,command ] ] ]
```

But I have no idea where to begin with it, or if it's the appropriate approach to take. The ultimate goal of this exercise is to discover how many terabytes `data_base` holds.

Answer (score 1):

sp_spaceused is probably a better start

```
data_base..sp_spaceused
```

You'll get something like

```
database_name database_size
------------- -------------
data_base     193636.0 MB

reserved    data        index_size  unused
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------
79990040 KB 56017848 KB 22623154 KB 1335938 KB
```

You can use it on individual tables too.